# Is there a classic Matrix Algebra reference?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

I'm looking for a classic matrix algebra reference, either introductory or advanced.

In fact, I'm looking for ways to factorize elements of a matrix, and its appropriate determinant implications.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by «classic»?

Comment: factorize elements of a matrix? That's a question about the ring from which the elements are taken, not a question about matrices. Do you want to rephrase your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F. R. Gantmacher's [The Theory of Matrices (2 Volumes)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821813935)(1959), AMS Chelsea Publishing (trans. K.A. Hirsch), is certainly a classic treatise.  I find it useful on occasion for its discussion of Lyapunov stability and eigenvalue/root location via Routh-Hurwitz (vol. 2), but the basics are well-covered in vol. 1.

A bit expensive to buy new, but worth your while keeping an eye out for used copies.

Answer (score 1):

*Golub* and *Van Loan*'s [*Matrix Computations*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801854148) is kind of a standard reference, but it is actually more oriented towards numerical linear algebra, with a strong emphasize of algorithmic questions, though not without extensive analyses of their theoretical foundations.

Answer (score 1):

Horn and Johnson's [Matrix Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521386322) is also widely used as a reference. Recently I came across Harville's [Matrix algebra from a statistician's perspective](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387783563), and it's pretty useful too (especially for vec operator and matrix derivatives).

Answer (score 0):

I think Halmos: "Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces" is regarded as a classic by many, though it has a more general approach, i.e. what many people might call "Linear Algebra done right"  or something along those lines
.