# Is there a standard operation to "rotate rings on matrices"?

Tags: matrices, reference-request

Is there some standard operation to "rotate rings on matrices"? Look at the image below:

[image]

The numbers around the four empty squares are what I'm calling *ring*, In the second matrix, this *ring* has been rotated counterclockwise. I'm aware that *ring* may not be the right name.

Comment: What should I review?

Comment: Ring is perhaps a poor choice of words, since it's very common to talk about "matrices defined over a ring", which has a very different meaning.

Comment: Oddly enough, if you do the same thing to $2\times 2$ matrices and restrict you attention to those of the form $$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & a\end{pmatrix}$$ then rotation counterclockwise corresponds to multiplication on the right by $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ while rotation clockwise corresponds to multiplication on the left by the same matrix.

Comment: @AlexBecker Yep, But I've explained it. It's also because my native languange is portuguese, I just didn't know which word to use. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the vector representation $\mathrm{vec}$ of your matrix $X$, by stacking all columns on top of each other:
$$
\mathrm{vec}\:
\pmatrix{
1 &4&2&6\\
7&\square&\square&2 \\
7&\square&\square&4 \\
8&2&5&6\\
}
=\pmatrix{
1 &4&2&6&
7&\square&\square&2 &
7&\square&\square&4 &
8&2&5&6\\
}^T.
$$
Now apply $\pi_{\text{rot.ring}}$, a permutation (matrix $M$, with dimension $4^2$) on $\mathrm{vec}\;X$, such that $\left(\mathrm{vec}\;X\right)_1$ is sent to $\left(\mathrm{vec}\;X\right)_5$, $\left(\mathrm{vec}\;X\right)_2$  to $\left(\mathrm{vec}\;X\right)_1$,...
So $\pi_{\text{rot.ring}}=\left(5,1,2,3,4,8,12,16,15,14,13,9\right)$ and $M_{j,j+1}=\left(\pi_{\text{rot.ring}}\right)_{j,j+1}$ and $M_{jj}=1$ if $j\in\{6,7,10,11\}$.

Undo the  $\mathrm{vec}$ operation and you'll get a matrix with your *ring* rotated.

Comment: Will this procedure work on matrices bigger than 4x4? And will the same procedure work for rotating the inner "rings"?

Comment: Sure, this will work for larger matrices and other rings (for the inner ring cycle the elements $\{6,7,10,11\}$).

Comment: @GustavoBandeira do you agree?

Comment: Actually I'll need to translate what you said - and also what others said - so I can apply it. I was just ashamed of asking for help but here it goes: What topics do I need to learn? I supose matrices are the topic, but could it be more specifical?

Comment: Are you asking for a good book on matrices? [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/105351/19341) you'll find some examples...

Comment: I'm a little afraid of studying it now, I'm in the beginning of calculus and discrete mathematics.

Comment: It's never too late: Fight your fear!

Comment: It's not fear, I thought this could damage my math learning or make me lose a leg or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure this operation has absolutely no interesting interpretation when the matrix is viewed as representing a linear transformation, as matrices usually are. It is therefore a fairly certain bet that this operation has no name.

Comment: I believed it has no name too, but I'm naive then I decided to ask.

Answer (score 3):

If you identify the space $M_{n\times n}$ with $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, and let $S_{n^2}$ act on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ by permuting the axes, then your operation corresponds to the action of a $4n-4$ cycle on $M_{n\times n}$. This interpretation is purely geometrical though, and does not give any understanding of how the operation affects the linear transformation corresponding to a matrix.

Comment: Will this procedure work on matrices bigger than 4x4? And will the same procedure work for rotating the inner "rings"?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Yes, it works for any $n$. And any "ring" as well,. However, you must choose the correct $4n-4$ cycle; not just any cycle will do.

Comment: What you mean with "cycle", is this a name for my "ring"?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira No, "cycle" is a technical term. It describes certain elements of the permutation group $S_{n^2}$. You can read about cycles on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: Oh, ok. I was confused because you suggested a better term instead of "ring".